# How do I get connection status from aws-iot-device-sdk

Tags: aws-sdk, mqtt, aws-iot

How do I check if the client is connected or not?

From the Device class example, I understand that the Device is an instance returned by `mqtt.Client()`
`mqtt.js` has a connected flag https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js#connected

However, `device.connected` gives me `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

I found a trick to get the current status 
To monitor that status after , you should use the device connected topic as suggested in previous answers
If you have Fleet indexing settings enabled 
make sure you enabled "Thing Connectivity" : Include thing connectivity data in your Thing Index.

Then you can run a search (for a specific Thing , or for a group of things) and get the connectivity status for each Thing:

```
`    AWS = require('aws-sdk');
     var iot = new this.AWS.Iot({
                    accessKeyId: this.AccessKeyId,   
                    secretAccessKey: this.SecretAccessKey,
                    //endpoint: this.host,
                    maxResults: 500,
                    region: this.regionData
                    }); 
    var params = {
              queryString: 'shadow.reported.isConnected.connected = *', 
              indexName: 'AWS_Things',
              nextToken: nexttoken 
            };
    iot.searchIndex(params, function(err, data)
    for (const robot of data.things[0])
        connectivity = robot.connectivity.connected;`
```

Note - the code above is a not a working example , just to show the principles
Note2 - remember search results comes in pages and need to handled that way

Answer (score 0):

Because its not there.

```
DeviceClient {
  publish: [Function],
  subscribe: [Function],
  unsubscribe: [Function],
  end: [Function],
  handleMessage: [Function: bound ],
  updateWebSocketCredentials: [Function],
  getWebsocketHeaders: [Function],
  updateCustomAuthHeaders: [Function],
  simulateNetworkFailure: [Function],
  _events: 
   { connect: [Function],
     close: [Function],
     reconnect: [Function],
     offline: [Function],
     error: [Function],
     message: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 6 }
```

Though you can listen to the "connect" event and add "connected" property yourself as shown below

```
device.on('connect', function() {
   device.connected = true;
});
```

Inspect DeviceClient again and now you have it.

```
DeviceClient {
  publish: [Function],
  subscribe: [Function],
  unsubscribe: [Function],
  end: [Function],
  handleMessage: [Function: bound ],
  updateWebSocketCredentials: [Function],
  getWebsocketHeaders: [Function],
  updateCustomAuthHeaders: [Function],
  simulateNetworkFailure: [Function],
  _events: 
   { connect: [Function],
     close: [Function],
     reconnect: [Function],
     offline: [Function],
     error: [Function],
     message: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 6,
  connected: true }
```

Comment: yup, thats what they said on the github issue I raised. They are not maintaining the `connected` property like `mqtt` does

Answer (score 0):

Create a rule in the IoT rules engine and listen to lifecycle events. The device connected topic will get a message when the IoT device is connected.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html

Comment: The whole point is to know if the device connection is active or not. If I'm using cloud for that, don't you think that would be insane?